# Why is QObjectIterator::get_value_ref() not implemented in my source distribution of QtLua?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, lua, cmake

I am trying to build the QtLua module for Qt 4.7.4 on my windows machine and I have the project all set up (thanks to cmake) with the appropriate include/lib paths and compiler/linker settings. But now I have a problem where the library wont build because of a seemingly missing implementation for ValueRef QObjectIterator::get_value_ref() located at line 145 of  qtluaobjectiterator.cc. I don't really know what to do about this, I tried returning a default value but there was no default constructor for ValueRef. This was all that was in the source file for the function:

```
ValueRef QObjectIterator::get_value_ref()
{
    // Not used from lua script
    std::abort();
}
```

It also appears that another function is also not implemented. Or at least not implemented to be buildable in MSVC2010, I don't actually know whether gcc is okay with functions not returning values they're supposed to, but I highly doubt it. qtluaenumiterator.cc line 58

```
ValueRef EnumIterator::get_value_ref()
{
    abort();
}
```

Info:

- Windows 7 x64 Ultimate
- Visual Studio 2010 ultimate (with MSVC10)
- luaforwindows v5.1.4-45
- QtLua v1.3
- QtSDK 4.7.4
- CMake 2.8.6

I have found virtually 0 items on this topic via google search (1 was in Russian, so I don't know if it could've helped)

Comment: Post that russian topic, i can translate it if there is useful info.

Comment: Unfortunately I seem to have "misplaced" it and cannot find the link right now :(

Comment: http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?s=424a67700dbc8b287011be67fd5c5f25&showtopic=327360

found it, also, it looks like just a question anyway

Comment: Nope, guy from that thread had problems which seem unrelated to this question. Dunno, then.

Answer (score 2):

These virtual functions reimplemented from the base class are never called when the object is a QObjectIterator or EnumIterator. There is no way to build a ValueRef from such iterator because the Qt metadata are not modifiable. A call to one of these functions would indicate a bug so it's fair to call std::abort here.

Moreover gcc knows that the std::abort function never returns so it does not require these functions to return a value after a call to abort.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's simply not implemented yet, but there is a workaround for VC++:

```
return ValueRef(Value(_ls), Value(_ls));
```

I guess GCC knows to ignore that the functions don't return a value because of the abort() function